# recv doesnt retrieve all messages

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, polling

my server only disp first message of any new clients, but not the other message sended, here is the code :

```
void init_serv(serv_t *serv)
{
    int i = 0;

    serv->ret = poll(serv->fds, serv->nfds, 0);
    if (serv->ret < 0)
    {
      perror("poll() failed");
      return;
    }
    serv->current_size = serv->nfds;
    for (i = 0; i < serv->current_size; i++) {
        if(serv->fds[i].revents == 0)
          continue;
        if(serv->fds[i].revents != POLLIN) {
            printf("Error! revents = %d\n", serv->fds[i].revents);
            serv->end_server = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (serv->fds[i].fd == serv->sockfd) {
            do {
                serv->newfd = accept(serv->sockfd, NULL, NULL);
                if (serv->newfd < 0) {
                    if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
                        perror("  accept() failed");
                        serv->end_server = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                serv->fds[serv->nfds].fd = serv->newfd;
                serv->fds[serv->nfds].events = POLLIN;
                serv->nfds++;
            } while (0);
        } else {
            serv->close_conn = 1;
            do {
                serv->ret = recv(serv->fds[i].fd, serv->buffer, sizeof(serv->buffer), 0);
                printf("Buffer = %s\n", serv->buffer);
                bzero(serv->buffer, sizeof(serv->buffer));
                if (serv->ret < 0) {
                    if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
                        perror("recv() failed");
                        serv->close_conn = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if (serv->ret == 0) {
                    printf("Connection closed\n");
                    serv->close_conn = 1;
                    break;
                }
            } while (1);
            if (serv->close_conn) {
                close(serv->fds[i].fd);
                serv->fds[i].fd = -1;
            }
        }
        serv->fds[i].revents = 0;
    }
}
```

i think the problem is from the `recv`, but how can i fix this to receive all the messages, from all differents clients ?
if i put the  `recv` in a loop `while (1)` i will recv all message, but only from the first client connected to the server, and i will receive other message, only if i break the loop...

Comment: poll should be part of your infinite loop. probably you placed 1 into your ```do ... while (1);``` loop by mistake

Comment: the function```init_server``` is on a while loop @MaximSagaydachny

Comment: you need to configure client socket as non-blocking(set O_NONBLOCK flag to the client socket) after accept , i.e.: ``` int flags = fcntl(serv->newfd,F_GETFL,0);fcntl(serv->newfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);``` and break out of your loop(without closing connection) when errno == EWOULDBLOCK. or should not call subsequent recv-s whithout calling poll prior recv

Comment: the poll is already unblockant.. @MaximSagaydachny

Comment: you need to break out of loop. and condition (serv->ret < 0) does not work because recv blocks on client socket (kernel has no data on second recv call and recv call blocks waiting for the data to appear in kernel). so the only way to break the loop is to disconnect client from server. Either replace 1 with 0  in while(1) or set client socket non-blocking for you to have a chance to get (serv->ret < 0).

Comment: This doesn't worked actually.. @MaximSagaydachny

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212420/discussion-between-zahreddine-laidi-and-maxim-sagaydachny).